# Compiling C++ project using Qt 5.7

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, compilation

Totally new to Qt and C++ (although had studied it long time ago).

I need to build a C++ Qt project. It asks for MSVC 2015. The build project file is not proper. I have no idea what to do. I installed VC redist and SDK but no success. Can someone please help me how to set up the build file so I build the project successfully?

The kit does not have compiler associated with it. and I don't know how to get it to work.

Edit: Adding attachment if I use mingw

[image]

Edit 2:

Kit configuration with MSVC2015:
[image]

What should be qmake statement?

Comment: Did you install visual studio 2015? If so Qt creator should pick up the compiler automatically.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to do. I mean if you installed qt-creator with the bundled mingw you would not need to worry at all about Visual Studio. Do you want to use Visual Studio? If so what version do you want? Do you have the c++ compiler installed in whatever version of Visual Studio you have installed. Recent Visual Studio free versions do not select the c++ compiler when installing so you have to take an extra step to install it.

Comment: It appears that you installed the Visual Studio 2013 version of Qt 5.7.1. Do you have Visual Studio 2013 installed? If so do you have the c++ compiler installed with Visual Studio 2013. No other option will work with the binaries for Qt that you installed. You can go back and install a mingw version of Qt if you don't want to use Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: oh, I wanted to use MSVC2015, as that is what was previously used I suppose. Can I get that in QT installable? or using mingw is sufficient?

Comment: Yes there are Qt binaries Visual Studio 2015. Yes mingw will work if you install the Qt binaries for that. Remember that binaries for 1 compiler are incompatible with binaries for all other compilers.